# JSON and file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, server, file-get-contents

i have really a big problem, i have created a login API, and i'm facing a problem, when i access my website from URL it gives me the Code :

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "user_data": {
    "username": "",
    "email": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "gender": "",
    "avatar": "",
    "cover": ""
  }
}
```

That's mean i have successfully received the data, but when i'm trying to get the data via file_get_contents(); it don't work, and start to give me php errors from the sender server:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "error_id": 2,
    "error": "User not logged in"
  }
}
```

and that's mean that the user is not logged in, but i'm logged in when i access the URL directly,

the question is how can i generate a JSON data to send it and receive it from another server or domain like Facebook graph, or soundcloud API, they both are working with **file_get_contents();**

Comment: if you would use curl you could handle a normal session, otherwise I would recommend you to add a `login via API` function. First step login to your API with a post (username and password), the API should return a token, on success. Then you have to put the token on every request you make (to identify the user). The token should have a time to live.

Comment: @swidmann thanks for the answer, i understand you, but how the token works? where should i store it ? to read it from another server?

Comment: well you should store the token in the database from your API, where you have the API login. Note: this is just an approach, there may be some better ways, but I think it will work in your case, just remember to that the token should not be valid forever

Comment: mmm, but how about receiving data from them ? it's like "select user_id from api_tokens where token = 'XXX'; and then fetch the data and then decode it as json? will it work ?

Comment: Yes something like that, if you always fetch the api_token you know which user it is, if the user is in the database and the token is still valid, you can give the other information the user is requesting. By the way if it´s sensitive data, i would always prefer a "curly" way with a real session and a post authentication

Comment: well you´re right with curl, but not all servers can handle file_get_contents(), that´s just configuration. And I´m sorry to say that, but If you want to sell that stuff you should have at least a little idea, how to do that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

How should your PHP script know, that you are logged in with your browser? Please take a look at oauth2. You have to implement the possibility to authorize your script to get access to the userdata.